# Cucumber-JVM considers all (@Given, @When, @Then) annotations to be interchangeable

Tags: java, annotations, cucumber-jvm

It has come (quite brutally) to my attention that with cucumber-JVM, when you define features whose steps have ***seemingly*** identical names they are considered interchangeable.

### Given

```gherkin
Feature: Grab that cash with both hands and make a stash

  Scenario: Spend it
    Given Jack has 5 dollars
    When  Jack wants to buy Lear Jet
    Then  He doesn't have enough cash

  Scenario: acquire it
    Given Jack is broke
    But   his wealth is slowly growing
    When  Jack has 5 dollars
    Then  He can afford a pack of gum

  Scenario: own it
    Given Jack is broke
    But   he has a job that's paid 5 dollar an hour
    When  He works an hour
    Then  Jack has 5 dollars
```

```java
@Given("^Jack has 5 dollars$")
public void set_it() throws Throwable {
    this.jack = new Person();
    jack.setCashAmount(5);
}

@When("^Jack has 5 dollars$")
public void wait_it() throws Throwable {
    jack.waitFor(wealth(is(equalTo(5))));
}

@Then("^Jack has 5 dollars$")
public void check_it() throws Throwable {
    assertThat("Jack should have 5 dollars by now",
               jack.getCashAmount(),
               is(equalTo(5)));
}
```

### When

I run this feature with cucumber (with mvn/intelliJ plugin/eclipse plugin/magical crystal ball/other ridiculous medium)

### Then

I get the following message :

```
cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in my.project.MySteps.wait_it() in file:[...] and my.project.MySteps.set_it() in file:[...]
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeGlue.addStepDefinition(RuntimeGlue.java:33)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.addStepDefinition(JavaBackend.java:151)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:41)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
...
```

And a bunch of other irrelevant line from which I'll spare you.

### Diagnostic

Cucumber does not seem to make a difference between `@Given("a")`, `@When("a")` and `@Then("a")` (and `@And` and `@But` which I don't really know what they were intended for in the first place since those are just syntactic sugar for "same as what I just did")

But as implementation suggest, those 3 steps are profoundly different from one another. Each sentence is properly describing what the test should do, and implementation that ensues is univocal.

- A "Given" step should setup the test pre-conditions
- A "When" step should trigger an action or await one
- A "Then" step should assert a state of the system afterward.

What am I missing there?

Is there a way to tell Cucumber how to rely not only on regexp but also on step types (which, to me, should be the default behavior)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how it is supposed to work. The step name by itself should be clear enough to see whether it is about test setup (Given), some action (When) or verifying the outcome (Then).

The action step can usually be worded so it contains a verb, for distinguishing setup and assertions I agree that it is sometimes quite difficult. You would have to come up with your own conventions here, one possibility could be the following:

```
Given Jack is broke
 When Jack earns 5 dollars
 Then Jack should have 5 dollars
```

Comment: The very fact that you say : "The step name by itself should be clear enough to see whether it is about test setup (Given), some action (When) or verifying the outcome (Then)." just proves that the adverb used IS important. There is no valid technical limitation to justify it, no semantic necessity to double the "given","when" or "then". I admit that my sentences are not the best examples but in essence, if a sentence makes a particular sense because of this adverb then there is no need to add to it by working one's way around this limitation.
Then why be redundant ?

Comment: One reason the keywords should be independent is that steps can be combined using `And`. Writing a scenario like `When something And anotherthing` reads more fluent than the alternative of `When something When anotherthing`.

Comment: Of course one reads way better than the other, yet `When A And B` remains just a nicer way to say what can be simplified (on a machine level) to `When A When B`.
As I said, `And` and `But` are just syntactic sugar, they stand here screaming : "Hey ! I'm just a more user friendly transcription of what was just before me !". What it can be reduced to remains a bunch of `given` `when` `then`.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnose is correct - the annotations do not matter, only the regular expression does.

What's more, you can define your own set of annotations in your favourite language to act as the keywords. How you understand them and use them is up to you.

Have a look inside the `cucumber-java.jar` - you'll find different annotation sets for different languages in the `cucumber.api.java` package (non-latin alphabets, too), eg. `en_pirate` version: `Avast`, `Aye`, `Blimey`, `Gangway`, `Letgoandhaul` ;)

There's no particular order or semantics of each of them - they are just regular expression holders.

---

**EDIT**

The annotations are independent from the expressions used in the feature files. You can use the default Given/When/Then in the feature files and the en_pirate `Avast`, `Aye`, `Blimey` annotations - Cucumber will match them.

However, the feature files themselves are parsed by the Gherkin parser (as rightly pointed out below by @Ar3s) and you can use one of the [supported spoken languages](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Spoken-languages) instead by putting a

```
#language: <language code, eg. fr>
```

on the first line of your feature file. You can find the mappings between the default English keywords and other languages in the [Gherkin i18n JSON](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/master/lib/gherkin/i18n.json). Still, the language of the feature file and the language of the annotations do not need to match.

Comment: Then, if they have no meaning in themselves, why not just have one big annotation that is `@Step`

Comment: Good question. I think (this is just an assumption) that a set of annotations allows the Cucumber runtime to define a set of keywords/prefixes that are allowed to be used in the feature files. That is, having "When" and "Then" annotations allows you to use them as the beginnings of the lines - Cucumber runtime will ignore the "When" and "Then" prefixes and will look only at the rest of the line to find the step to execute. That way you can write nice sentences like "When Jack has 5 dollars" and not "Step Jack has 5 dollars".

Comment: That's not the case since feature files are parsed by Gherkin3 (https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin3) and not cucumber itself.

Plus that would be a very weird and inefficient way to determine which keywords are accepted in a feature file to have to scan for annotations classes simple names ...

Comment: I did some research and it turns out the Gherkin parser is independent of the annotations. See my edit. Thanks for pointing it out!